# Missing Browserlink in VS2019, Where is browserlink acquired / loaded from normally?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

My local install of VS2019 (16) seems to be missing references to BrowserLink. I've tried repairing the installation, and installing multiple different SDK's to no avail.

**Where is BrowserLink normally located? And what is the mechanism that causes it to be loaded in development versions?** It doesn't seem to be packaged seperately from VS since version 12, unless you are using the new .net core versions.

We have checked the GAC, NuGET, and are running out of options.

It's a .net 4.5 project, if that's relevent.

```
Could not locate assembly Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Runtime, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a in the Assembly Stores configured.  Requesting assembly:
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Exception: Could not locate assembly Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Runtime, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a in the Assembly Stores configured.  Requesting assembly:
```

The root cause is almost certainly something to do with the dumb way this project has a shared non-standard assembly cache, and doesn't fallback to normal dev locations, but the question is about what the normal location/mechanism is for BrowserLink (16) to be loaded.

Comment: Things like Hot Reload are replacing legacy approaches, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have installed your VS2019 in default options, you can find the Browser Link library files in this path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Browser Link
```

(Replace the path of your installation location as appropriate)

You can then decide whether to copy Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.*.dll to the assembly cache of your application or include this path in your application.